# css drop down menu positioned incorrectly

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Hi guys this is my CSS code for a drop down menu:

```
#nav {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background-color:#60625C;
bottom:0;
left:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
}
#nav, #nav ul {
line-height:40px;
list-style-image:none;
list-style-position:outside;
list-style-type:none;
width:100%;
}
#nav a, #nav a:hover {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
border:medium none;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li {
float:left;
list-style-image:none;
list-style-position:outside;
list-style-type:none;
border-right:1px solid #6E7073;
}
#nav a, #nav a:visited {
color:#FFFFFF;
display:block;
padding:0 20px;
}
#nav a:hover, #nav a:active, .current_page_item a, #home .on {
text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li ul {
border-bottom:1px solid #6E7073;
height:auto;
left:-999em;
line-height:30px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position:absolute;
width:222px;
}
#nav li li {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background:#1E1F21 none repeat scroll 0 0;
border-left:1px solid #6E7073;
border-right:1px solid #6E7073;
border-top:1px solid #6E7073;
width:220px;
}
#nav li li a, #nav li li a:visited {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background:#1E1F21 none repeat scroll 0 0;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:0.9em;
font-weight:normal;
}
#nav li li a:hover, #nav li li a:active {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background:#60625C none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul, #nav li li.sfhover ul, #nav li li li.sfhover ul {
left:auto;
}
```

However the menu is being placed in an unwanted position at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

How can I make it display between the title and main content of the blog?

[image]

This is the code relating to the navigation in 'header.php'

```
<div id="navbar">
<div id="nav">      
<ul>
  <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">Home</a></li>
    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=0&sort_column=menu_order&exclude=56'); ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: a jsfiddle would be a great help.

Comment: On your `#nav` you have `bottom:0;left:0;`. If you have `bottom:0;` it will display at the bottom. Try something like `top:250px;` and check if its way to much or needs more. Also, did you modify that wordpress theme right? Whats the theme name?

Comment: This code looks a bit of a mess in my opinion. I think it would be good to remove it and start over and enhance it while you progress and add more to it. Also, I really do not see the point of the absolute positioning of #nav. It just makes positioning it more annoying. If you could add more code that are related to the navigation, like what comes before and what comes after, it would help a lot.